# How to import local images from JSON in react?

Tags: reactjs, json, image, absolute-path

I am buliding react app and i am getting images path from JSON file:

```
"images": {
"planet": "./images/planet-mercury.svg", 
"internal": "./images/planet-mercury-internal.svg", 
"geology": "./images/geology-mercury.png"
}
```

I am destructuring JSON file, and this it how i am trying to display images:

```
<img src={images.planet} alt="IMG" />
```

My images folder is located in the public directory with index.html. But images doesn`t display. How to show my local stored images?

Comment: use absolute path `/images/geology-mercury.png`

Comment: Nothing is displaying on localhost:3000. Although my code from question works on GH Pages website.